# Java, JMenuBar, JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, jmenubar

Currently, I'm working on a small program in JAVA. I am using JMenuBar with JMenuItem to display various options for users. But ass you can see in screenshot JMenuItem list has top and bottom borders painted in grey colour.

My Problem is that I would like it to be in black colour to match JMenuBar and JMenuItem background colours but I cannot find a way to do it.

Here is a piece of code for this GUI part.

```
// build the MenuBar menus
    EmployeeMenu = new JMenu("Employee");
    EmployeeMenu.setForeground(Color.white);
    EmployeeMenu.setFont(new Font("Arial", 9, 20));
    EmployeeMenu.setBorderPainted(false);
    EmployeeMenu.setOpaque(false);

    newEmployeeMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Add new");
    newEmployeeMenuItem.setBackground(Color.black);
    newEmployeeMenuItem.setForeground(Color.white);
    newEmployeeMenuItem.addActionListener(this);
    newEmployeeMenuItem.setBorderPainted(false);

    DeleteEmployeeMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Delete");
    DeleteEmployeeMenuItem.addActionListener(this);
    DeleteEmployeeMenuItem.setBackground(Color.black);
    DeleteEmployeeMenuItem.setForeground(Color.white);
    DeleteEmployeeMenuItem.setBorderPainted(false);
```

And a ScreenShot of output is here.

[image: Just an Image]

Also, how can I repaint selected item from MenuBar? (Right now it's on default (LightBlue) but it does not match with the black background colour.

Any help appreciated and a
Huge **thank you** in advance!

Comment: You're looking at the popup window used by `JMenu` to display the items, it's not a border.  A better solution might be to change the default colors the look and feel is using

Comment: Any hints how to change the default look and feel colors in easy way?

Comment: `UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put` - of course you will need to know the keys you're replacing, you can scan through the key/value pairs from the `UIDefaults` which is just an extension to `Hashtable`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I used 

     UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("PopupMenu.background", Color.black);

and the area of light grey coloured popup window reduced to smaller but did not disappear completely.

Comment: http://imgur.com/rctobiH Here is image of output after setting UIManagerLookAndFeel

Comment: `PopupMenu.border` <- try setting that to an `EmptyBorder` - just know, this will affect ALL popups

Comment: Done Thank you so much! @MadProgrammer